# didSelectRowAtIndexPath index path with uisearchcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have an application when the user clicks on a cell it will open another viewController and I just add a `uisearchcontroller` on my tableview.

When I am searching on the tableview the result is correct ,
but when I click on the cell after filtering , it opens the wrong page.

My problem is I don't now how to identify the `indexpath` when the `uiviewcontroller` is active to make the result open correct page

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        IndexPathRow = indexPath.row


        performSegueWithIdentifier("toView2", sender: self)
}
```

**Edit**

I solved my problem by adding new variable in the struct of type integer and then modify didSelectRowAtIndexPath function to

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

if resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != ""{

      IndexPathRow = filteredData[indexPath.row].i
    }

    else {
        IndexPathRow = indexPath.row

    }

    performSegueWithIdentifier("toView2", sender: self)

    }
```

Comment: You need to supply more info. You should have some sort of method for storing what is in the various cells (like an array of cell info). Then the row can correspond to the element located at that spot in the array.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to get the selected item, is to call `indexPathForSelectedRow()` method inside of the segue delegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("toView2", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toView2" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            print("IndexPathRow =  \(indexPath.row)")
            //destination controller code goes here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got this error " Variable used within its own initial value" in indexPath.row

Comment: maybe you run this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?  You should run this code in `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the data with your main array, try to get the data with the searched array, then only its correct, check for `searchController.isActive()` on all the method related to the main array, basically check for this in your `prepareForSegue`